# If $1 < p < \infty$, $p, q$ are congujages, $x \in \ell^{p}$, show that $\{|x_j|^{p - 1}\} \in \ell^q$

Tags: functional-analysis

If $1 < p < \infty$, $p, q$ are congujages, $x \in \ell^{p}$, show that $\{|x_j|^{p - 1}\} \in \ell^q$.

I'm trying to show that $\left(\sum |x_j|^{p-1} \right)^\frac 1q < \infty$. 
However, manipulating the relation between $p - 1$ and $q$ doesn't yield any result.

Any help will be appeciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ you get $p+q=qp$, or $p=q(p-1)$.  Thus we have 
$$\sum_j(|x_j|^{p-1})^q=\sum_j|x_j|^{q(p-1)}=\sum_j|x_j|^p<\infty,$$
and thus $\{|x_j|^{p - 1}\} \in \ell^q$.

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$\frac1p + \frac1q = 1 \implies \frac1q = 1 - \frac1p = \frac{p-1}p \implies q = \frac{p}{p-1}$$

Hence

$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \left(|x_j|^{p-1}\right)^q = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \left(|x_j|^{p-1}\right)^{\frac{p}{p-1}} = \sum_{j=1}^\infty|x_j|^{p} < +\infty$$

since $x \in \ell^p$.